# Fastest RAM and SSD upgrades I can put in my Macbook Pro 2009?

Tags: windows-10, memory, ssd, macbook, macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro 2009 as per: https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.53-aluminum-15-mid-2009-sd-unibody-specs.html

I have 8 GB RAM and an SSD, but I'm getting pretty terrible performance scores as per: https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/45575043

Yes I could get a faster/newer computer...but failing that, are those test results the best I can ever get from the Mac hardware, or is there a make or spec of Mem and/or SSD I can get that would give me noticeably better performance?

Or any other config changes I could make?

I did find this re enabling XMP and wondering if that would make a difference (perhaps with a change in mem): [How do I flash my RAM's SPD to make it work with a MacBook Pro?](https://superuser.com/questions/316845/how-do-i-flash-my-rams-spd-to-make-it-work-with-a-macbook-pro)

I am happy swapping out bits of hardware (as long as no soldering involved) and making config changes. Yes I run Win 10 on it...

Thanks.

Comment: Fractionally faster memory will seldom make a difference outside of benchmarks.  Unless your system is starved for memory faster memory nor enabling XMP will likely make a measurable noticeable difference.  The most likely issue you have is your processor is more than a decade old and there is nothing you can do about that. This also means you have slower memory in general compared to even the slowest DDR4 on the market.  You are likely not using a NVMe SSD but instead SATA (I know little about Macbooks so if that isn't correct don't hold it against me).

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, that's helpful. Yes SSD is SATA. I'm not so much after better benchmarks, just after the fastest I can make this particular machine.

Comment: On an '09, you very probably have only SATA 2.0 which will limit the SSD speeds. tbh, you're not going to squeeze any more out of it in practical terms. It has a dog-slow CPU/GPU & attendant hardware by today's standards [& it wasn't lightning-fast even when new, laptops from that period were heavily compromised compared to modern ones. Desktops were fast, laptops weren't.]. The SSD upgrade was the best improvement you'll get out of it.